# Custom HID not recognized as input device

Tags: linux, input, usb, hid, joystick

I used an ESP32-S3 with [TinyUSB](https://github.com/hathach/tinyusb) to create a custom [HID device](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_4.pdf).

The descriptor I used is:

```
0x05, 0x01,        // Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x37,        // Usage (Dial)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x09, 0x37,        //   Usage (Dial)
0x15, 0x9C,        //   Logical Minimum (-100)
0x25, 0x64,        //   Logical Maximum (100)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x04,        //   Report Count (4)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0xC0,              // End Collection

// 19 bytes
```

Which is meant to support 4 input dials of 8-bit each.

When I plug in my device to a linux host PC, this is reported:

```
kernel: usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=303a, idProduct=4004, bcdDevice= 1.00
kernel: usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: usb 1-5: Product: TurboLEDz QuadDial
kernel: usb 1-5: Manufacturer: GSAS Inc.
kernel: usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 000001
mtp-probe[1217981]: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5"
mtp-probe[1217981]: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
kernel: hid-generic 0003:303A:4004.00E4: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [GSAS Inc. TurboLEDz QuadDial] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
```

Note that hid-generic reports it as **hiddev0,hidraw0**

But `evtest` will not recognize it as input device.

Compare this with a (throttle) joystick that I plug in, which is reported as:

```
hid-generic 0003:068E:00FA.00C8: input,hidraw12: USB HID v1.00 Joystick [CH PRODUCTS CH THROTTLE QUADRANT] on usb-0000:00:14.0-11/input0
```

Note that it reports as **input,hidraw12**

What is the magic sauce I need to have the PC see it as an input HID device?

Comment: I think you may have to choose a usage for the Application Collection that has the CA type (the Dial usage type is DV -  Dynamic Value). The spec says "An operating system uses the Usage associated with this [application] collection to link the device to its controlling application or driver.". I would try specifying a CA usage of Keyboard or maybe Game Pad as it is conceivable that those devices could have a Dial control on them. Worth a shot :)

Comment: @aja Thank you, if you write it up as answer I will mark it as such. I ended up trying usages gamepad and joystick, which gave me an input device, but there was a dead-zone enforced causing small values to be set to zero. So in the end I had to go with `Page: Desktop Usage: Pointer` which sounds strange, but the CH PRODUCT throttle did the same.